# Regex to match any HTML attribute value and quotes

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have seen this question on SO before, but it was specific to a tag or attribute

I need to match any attribute values with a regex. I have the following, which matches both the attribute and value:

```
(\S+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?
```

But, I only want it to match the value and quotes around the value. It also needs to account for single and double quotes.

**I understand the suggestions to avoid doing this with HTML and to use a parser, but this is a specific needed situation. I am only using it to color code the attribute value.**

Any help?

Comment: I'd recommend using an html parser instead.

Comment: Best advice - don't use regex for parsing HTML. It is just a really bad idea and will break when you need it most.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I understand the advice, but in this situation it is needed.

Comment: You can always write your own sort of parser that can look at each tag type and then for any possible valid attributes for that particular tag extract the values with regex.

Comment: The truth is you should use existing tools to do this. WebKit can help you. Otherwise use NSXMLParser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I made a slight mod to your regex string.**

I replaced the `(\S+)=` with `(?<==)`.

I think your regex implementation should be able to do a positive lookbehind.

This regex will show inconsistency when presented with quotes/doublequotes nested inside themselves like this: `<a onclick='StackExchange.switchMobile("on")'>mobile</a>`

You may want to look into changing your character classes to get around that.

**Here's the full regex string:**

`(?<==)["']?((?:.(?!["']?\\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?`

---

As per our online chat discussion, I came up with a new regex which is shorter and much cleaner:

`(?<==)('|").*?\1(?=.*?>)`

What this regex does is as follows:

1. Assert that we can find a `=` symbol - `(?<==)`
2. Followed by a single/double quote (place this into a capture group) - `('|")`
3. Match anything (non-greedy) until we find another quote of the same type - `.*?\1`
4. Assert that there is a closing tag `>` somewhere ahead of our match - `(?=.*?>)`

Comment: That worked! Thanks for bearing with me on this and helping me out. It is a pain like you said when people just say "use a parser".

Comment: No problem! I have a passion for regex and refuse to back down from a challenge. Just remember that you will encounter issues when it comes to things nested inside themselves. In this case, it's the quotes that might cause issues.

Comment: Thanks. Any resources where I can learn regex? It seems super confusing to me.

Comment: I started at http://www.regular-expressions.info , then I got a copy of RegexBuddy (commercial application) which helped me understand Regex more as it gives information about each token as I am creating a string. You could probably use http://www.regex101.com instead of RegexBuddy, they do practically the same thing.

Comment: So there is no way to get around the nested quotes issue? What did you mean by You may want to look into changing your character classes to get around that."?

Comment: The reason it is matching quotes nested within themselves is because you have a character class which will match either `'` or `"`. I don't think there is a way around that, unless you know 100% for certain that every single set of values is going to be wrapped in either one or the other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46652/discussion-between-nic-hubbard-and-vasili-syrakis)